# "You have an error in your SQL syntax " after upgrade to CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

After I updated my web site to [CodeIgniter 3](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/), I got this error

My code:

```
  public function get_pickedItems(){
    $this->db->select('p.user_id,u.user_name,u.email,u.full_name,u.thumbnail,u.address,u.phone_no,u.postal_code,u.state,u.country,u.city');
    $this->db->from(USER_PAYMENT.' as p');
    $this->db->join(USERS.' as u' , 'p.user_id = u.id');
    $this->db->join(PRODUCT.' as pd' , 'pd.id = p.product_id'); 
    $this->db->where('p.user_id > 1 GROUP BY p.user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('p.id','ASC');
    return $this->db->get();
  }
```

The error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`p`.`user_id` ORDER BY `p`.`id` ASC' at line 5

SELECT `p`.`user_id`, `u`.`user_name`, `u`.`email`, `u`.`full_name`, `u`.`thumbnail`, `u`.`address`, `u`.`phone_no`, `u`.`postal_code`, `u`.`state`, `u`.`country`, `u`.`city` FROM `shopsy_user_payment` as `p` JOIN `shopsy_users` as `u` ON `p`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` JOIN `shopsy_product` as `pd` ON `pd`.`id` = `p`.`product_id` WHERE `p`.`user_id` > `1 GROUP BY` `p`.`user_id` ORDER BY `p`.`id` ASC

Filename: models/User_model.php

Line Number: 462
```

The only thing that I changed that related with database was the config/database.php file.

> Due to 3.0.0’s renaming of Active Record to Query Builder, inside your
>   config/database.php, you will need to rename the $active_record
>   variable to $query_builder

```
$active_group = 'default';
// $active_record = TRUE;
$query_builder = TRUE;
```

Comment: seems pretty obvious from the error message...

Comment: yes pretty obvious :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty obvious from the error message, don't use `GROUP BY` in `where`.

Codeigniter's [Active Record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) has support for this:

```
$this->db->group_by('p.user_id');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the full query - Your Group By is misplaced.

```
 $this->db->group_by('p.user_id');
```